# When can we use the words "presume" and "assume"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, synonyms

According to Merriam-Webster, **presume** means

1. to expect or assume especially with confidence
2. to suppose to be true without proof

while **assume** means

1. to pretend to have or be
2. to take as granted or true

Does it mean they are somewhat synonymous and can be used in a sentence interchangeably? For example,

> Students, tomorrow we will have a school activity, therefore we will
>   have no Science class. However, there will be checking of attendance
>   at 8:00 in the morning. I'll ***assume/presume*** that you are absent
>   the whole day if your names are not on the list.

Comment: Yes, they are "somewhat synonymous". But idiomatically native speakers would almost always say *I will **assume** [default assumption] if [a certain condition arises].* I think this may be something to do with the fact that the hypothetical condition and reaction are in a possible *future*, since *I presume you were absent yesterday, since your name isn't on the list* is far more acceptable to me (but still probably less common than the ***assume*** version). But there's probably more to it than that.

Comment: To *presume* involves *presumption* and is therefore *presumptuous*  there is no corresponding *assumptuous*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The words can often be used interchangeably. They have subtly different meanings that you should keep in mind when using them -- but don't assume a speaker or writer who is using them understands the difference!

"Assume" implies a bit more finality than "presume." It is more appropriate when a decision has been made, or is about to be made, with incomplete information.

> "We didn't know how many people would be at the event, so we *assumed* that 100 chairs would be enough. (the decision was made)
>   "Since you didn't reply to my earlier email, I *assume* that you will not be joining us at the meeting." (implies that the speaker is ready to act without additional feedback from the recipient)

"Presume" gives a bit more room for the listener to correct the speaker. Using "presume" instead of "assume" adds an implied "but correct me if I am wrong" to the end of a statement.

> "I *presume* you want chicken for dinner[, but correct me if I am wrong]."

In the past tense, "presumed" carries a bit of humility (if referring to oneself) or judgment (if referring to someone else), and it may imply that the presumption was incorrect in hindsight.

> "I *presumed* that she would not object[, but she did object]."
>   "They *presumed* to know my intentions[, but they did not]."

"Assumed" is more neutral, and does not imply anything about the outcome of the assumption. If you want to communicate that the assumption was correct or incorrect, that fact will need to be made explicit.

> "I *assumed* that the dog would not bite. I was wrong."
>   "She *assumed* that there would be enough cookies, and she was right."

The following examples contrast the two words and explain their implications:

> **Present tense:**
>   "You have not told me what kind of ice cream you want. I **assume** vanilla will be fine."
>   *(Even if the listener says nothing, the speaker will give them vanilla ice cream)*
>
> "You have not told me what kind of ice cream you want. I **presume** vanilla will be fine."
>   *(The speaker would like the listener to confirm or reject the presumption. They will probably wait for an answer before giving the listener any ice cream)*
>
> **Past tense:**
>   "Alice **assumed** I would like chocolate cake for my birthday."
>   *(The speaker may or may not have liked chocolate cake. It would be risky to guess without more information)*
>
> "Alice **presumed** I would like chocolate cake for my birthday."
>   *(This is a subtly judgmental statement. Alice probably got it wrong.)*

**Final Disclaimer:**
All of this is based upon present day, American usage. The words could carry different connotations in other countries or in older usage.

Comment: In fact I think slightly the opposite, *Presumption* involves taking liberties that might not really be one’s to take and so rather than humility it might be considered slightly rude.  *presume* is often collocated with *how dare you*:  ‘How dare you presume to know what I might like or dislike!”

Comment: @Jim, I think we are actually in agreement. Presume in the *present* tense is slightly rude, while presume in the *past* tense is more an of an admission of past rudeness -- hence the humility.

Answer (score 0):

I would say both Latin verbs are synonymous with assume being more common.
So we can express the same idea with to suppose/assume/presume (arranged in order of frequency).